# How do you properly connect mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, discord, discord.js, connection

I have this, but it bring up a ton of errors. Any suggestions?

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.SRV, {
useNewUrlParser: true,
useUnifiedTopology: true, 
useFindAndModify: false
}).then(() =>{
console.log('Connected to database!')
}).catch((err) =>{
console.log(err)
});
```

Here are the errors:

```
MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Code\bots\BuyBot\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:688:11)
at C:\Code\bots\BuyBot\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:348:10
at C:\Code\bots\BuyBot\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:5
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at promiseOrCallback (C:\Code\bots\BuyBot\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:30:10)
at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\Code\bots\BuyBot\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1140:10)
at Mongoose.connect (C:\Code\bots\BuyBot\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:347:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Code\bots\BuyBot\index.js:17:10)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

I have not idea what it is so mad about.

Comment: Include the errors you are getting

Comment: Have you tried looking at the docs for Mongoose

Comment: It means you don't have a environmental variable named `SRV` or you didn't correctly set up `process.env`. Are you using [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) or a similar module to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Create a .env file in the root folder and add the following line in that file. Don't forget to include dotenv package in your application.

```
SRV="Your_Mongo_URI"
```

And now run the code, this might work for you.